# what algorithm is used by google to recognize songs?

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-recognition

I've googled around (which really should be revealing how deep their grip of the world goes :P ) and haven't found any details about the actual algorithm. Just a jumping off point to start researching is all I need. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

They use a weighted finite state transducer, basically a Gaussian Mixture Model with clustering using an appropriate representation of the music.

http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/37754.pdf